# searchable combobox dropdown list Word Vba

Tags: ms-word

With WORD userform1.combobox1.list, Looking for searchable combo box that show matched items from the list in the combobox drop down list
the items will be like a full name, so when user type any chart that came in the beginning of first or middle or last name, it will show as matched

Comment: Please include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with a sample of your  input data and expected output so that others may better understand what you're trying to accomplish. Be sure to include notes on any methods you have already tried to solve the problem.

Comment: Combobox will have items like names, when I click any chart that match with beginning of and name, the combobox show only matched, its normal searching method